# OWIN throws error on startup, can't find entry method

Tags: asp.net, owin, startup, middleware

I recently added new middleware to my ASP.Net project which required me to adapt my startup method to

```
public void Configuration(IApplicationBuilder app)
```

instead of

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
```

I adapted my code to still work with owin by creating the said IAppBuilder myself, but I am now having problems to even get into the new startup method.

At start, OWIN causes a server error, see:

[image]

Apparently OWIN wants to find its own entry point first, so it fails as the configuration is configured towards the other middleware.

What's weird though is that I do have the correct method (`void Configure(IAppBuilder app)`) in another file belonging to the same partial Startup class.

The entry point I would expect to be called looks like this:

```
    public void Configuration(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOwin(setup => setup(next =>
        {
            var builder = new AppBuilder();
            var lifetime = (IApplicationLifetime)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IApplicationLifetime));

            var properties = new AppProperties(builder.Properties);
            properties.AppName = app.ApplicationServices.GetApplicationUniqueIdentifier();
            properties.OnAppDisposing = lifetime.ApplicationStopping;
            properties.DefaultApp = next;

            Configure(builder);

            return builder.Build<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>>();
        }));
....
```

So owin is actually being handled here. Can I somehow change the order of middleware load?

Comment: `IApplicationBuilder` is from *asp.net-core*. Appears you may be mixing versions.

Comment: @Nkosi I kind of know, but apparently that is what the asp net react lib works with